# Count days between current row and last row with distinct value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a  dataframe like:

```
        date  store   item    price  sales
0 2013-02-01     59  22154   999.00    1.0
1 2013-03-01     25   2552   899.00    1.0
2 2013-05-01     25   2552   899.00   -1.0
3 2013-06-01     25   2554  1709.05    1.0
4 2013-01-15     25   2555  1099.00    1.0
```

Now I am interested to get the days between each row and the row in past which has a price value different than the current one.

So I would like to have an extra column with the days how long time ago the price was different.

```
        date  store   item    price  sales  days_since
0 2013-02-01     59  22154   999.00    1.0   NaN
1 2013-03-01     25   2552   899.00    1.0   0
2 2013-05-01     25   2552   899.00   -1.0   1
3 2013-06-01     25   2554  1709.05    1.0   0
4 2013-01-15     25   2555  1099.00    1.0   0
```

In this example we just have 1 price which did not changed since yesterday.

How would I do that in the easiest way? Apply/Tranform/rolling window?

Thanks!

Comment: can you define what you mean by `current` and `each_one` ? given your current requirements I would assume row 1 should have a value of 28 days as the price is different? also your dates aren't sorted and you have a store & item, do you need to group by store/item code and item as well ?

Comment: I hope it is clear from the example? current mean just for each row and look at the past rows frorm this as reference... Take a date and count the number of days when the price was different.

Comment: then `df.groupby([df['price'].ne(df['price'].shift())])['date'].diff()` should work but your output does not match your logic to me maybe I'm not understanding it.

Comment: But shift is only for one day? Could you explain what it does. what is ne?

Comment: `shift` works at a row level - try `df['price'].shift()` to see the output. `ne` means `not equal` similair in other languages like powershell `-ne and -eq`

Comment: But I dont' knwo how many days. This check just the previous day, right? Si I need to count the days until the difference is not 0 anymore...

Comment: I try to check your code. but it is diffuclt to understand. could you please explain it?

Comment: Your solution is not the answer as compute the differences per group of true or false. But to get days in between I realize that you need somehow subtract rows with both Trues and False with True rows...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222716/discussion-between-manakin-and-ctiid).

Answer (score 1):

You wrote about counting days between the current and previous row,
so in my opinion the first step is to sort your DataFrame by *date*
(I assume that this column is of *datetime* type):

```
wrk = df.sort_values('date')
```

To compute the number of days define the following function:

```
def dayNo(grp):
    key = grp.grKey.iloc[0]
    if key > 1:
        return pd.Series((grp.date - lastDate[key - 1]).dt.days, index=grp.index)
    return pd.Series(0, index=grp.index)
```

For now skip it, I will explain details later.

And now the main code:

1. Start from computing "group key" column:

   ```
   wrk['grKey'] = wrk.price.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
   ```

   It assigns consecutive numbers to each sequence of rows with the same price.
2. Compute an auxiliary *Series* - the last date in each of the above groups:

   ```
   lastDate = wrk.groupby('grKey').date.last()
   ```
3. Now return to *dayNo* function.

   - `key` is the current grouping key (the first group is a "special case").
   - `lastDate[key - 1]` is the last date from the previous group.
   - `(grp.date - ...).dt.days` is the number of days since the last
     row in the previous group (when there was the previous price).
   - `return pd.Series(..., index=grp.index)` returns a *Series* with
     the above values and the index copied from the current group.
   - `return pd.Series(0, index=grp.index)` is the result for the
     first group (the initial date). My proposition is to return
     *0* here, so that the resulting column was not coerced to
     *float*.
4. Apply the above function to each group, generating the new column:

   ```
   wrk['days_since'] = wrk.groupby('grKey').apply(dayNo).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
   ```

   *reset_index* is needed to drop additional index level, introduced by *groupby*.
5. Drop *grKey* column:

   ```
   wrk.drop(columns=['grKey'], inplace=True)
   ```

The result is:

```
        date  store   item    price  sales  days_since
4 2013-01-15     25   2555  1099.00    1.0           0
0 2013-02-01     59  22154   999.00    1.0          17
1 2013-03-01     25   2552   899.00    1.0          28
2 2013-05-01     25   2552   899.00   -1.0          89
3 2013-06-01     25   2554  1709.05    1.0          31
```

Discussion of the result:

- *2013-01-15* - the initial date (no previous date), so, according
  to my proposition, the result is *0*.
- *2013-02-01* - *17* days passed from the previous row and the price has changed.
- *2013-03-01* - one month passed and the price has changed.
- *2013-05-01* - since the price has **not** changed, the last row with
  a distinct price is *2013-02-01* and since this date *89* days have passed.
- *2013-06-01* - *31* days passed from the previous row (price has changed).